# How to store a list from a for loop and then reuse it?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that generates a new list from an existing list using some formula. Then the newly generated list does the same. The problem I am having is, that i don't know hot to store all those generated lists.

```
lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
m = 0
c = 0
full_list = []
full_list.append(lst)
print(full_list)

while m <= 3:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        c = 2 * lst[i]
        lst[i] = c
    full_list.append(lst)
    m += 1
    print(full_list)
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

However I am getting:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
[[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
[[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

It seem that when I append the generated list to the *full list* it updates all the previous entries. How do I avoid that? Is there some other command than *append*?

**NOTE:**
I know this particular code example could be easily done with *numpy*, but I wanted to present a simple example here that is easily understood and I didn't want to write the complicated algorithm here. But the solution that solves the problem here will solve the problem with my original code.

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`, it clashes with the built-in list.

Comment: I edited it out.

Comment: But do you want a `list` containing all your `list`s or not? this output `[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]` looks very consistent to me. why would you rather in **only one case** to have an independent `list`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: @katardin's answer solves your problem I think, I just wanted to add that the problem with your code is that lst is a pointer to your actual list object, so everytime you call lst[i] = ... , it changes the ith element of lst, even the one you've already appended to your full_list because they are pointing to the same object. If you want to change that you need a deepcopy of your list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
full_list = []
full_list.append(lst)

while len(full_list) < 3:
    print(full_list)
    full_list.append( [ item *2 for item in full_list[-1] ] )
print(full_list)
```

This shortens your while loop logic, ties your while count to the length of the list you're trying to generate, and uses list comprehension to generate your new lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it without the list comprehension:

```
lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
full_list = [lst]

while len(full_list) <= 3:
    # Creating an empty list to work with
    working_list = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        # Updating the working variable with 2 * lst
        working_list.append(2 * lst[i])

    # Changing the original list to the updated version.
    # That way a list of [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] will be multiplied by 2 next.
    lst = working_list

    # Storing the updated version in a separate list of lists
    full_list.append(working_list)

print(full_list)
```

Sometimes creating a working variable to edit, separate from the original variable, is easier to work with.